# Changing Login to Logout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to change the Login button to Logout when a user is logged in. With the current code, the button actually does as its supposed to do (hitting login will bring up the form to login), but the button ends up still saying Login but it will let the user Logout. Here is my code:

```js
  const handleSignOut = () => {
    push("/");
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  };
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false)
 
 
 {login ? (
                <Link
                  className="link"
                  to="/"
                  onClick={() => {
                    handleSignOut(); setLogin(false);
                  }}
                >
                  Logout
                </Link>
              ) : (
                  <Link className="link" to="/">
                    Login
                  </Link>
                
              )}
```

I have included both the handlesignout and the usestate for login which is initially set to false.

Comment: Please include your `callback` for `setLogin`.

Comment: i think whenever you login you need to setLogin(true)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set initial state to be true;

const [login, setLogin] = useState(true) // it is false in your post

This should work.

```js
// login.js
const handleSignOut = () => {
    push("/");
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  };
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(true)

 const handleSubmit = () => {
   setLogin(false);
 }
 
 
 {login ? (
                
             <Link className="link" to="/">
                    Login
             </Link>
              ) : (
                  <Link
                    className="link"
                    to="/"
                    onClick={() => {
                       handleSignOut(); 
                       setLogin(true);
                    }}
                  >
                  Logout
                  </Link>
                
              )}

     // assuming this is your form
     // in your Form component on submitting, call this callback 
     "handleSubmit"
     <Form 
       onSubmit={handleSubmit}
     />
```

Comment: So, Something odd is happening when I use this code. It somewhat works, but I have to "login" twice. I'd initially login, and it would still show "login", I'd press it and it would take me to the login form, although I was still logged in (this code has it where certain things can't be accessed if logged out", If I hit login again it would change the button to logout. Furthermore if I press the button repeatedly it will keep changing despite being logged in or logged out.

Comment: Please add the code snippet of your form, is it a separate component? If that's the case we need to use setLogin on submitting the form.

Comment: nvm @NatsukoIzuki I have updated my answer with a callback, give it a try and let me know if it works.